# Saving a text file from a PDF in Notepad using VBA without SendKeys

Tags: vba, pdf, text

So, what I am trying to do is take a pdf file, open it with internet explorer, copy the text from it, paste that text to a text file in Notepad and save that file with the same name as the pdf that it was created from. I have accomplished all of this so far with the exception of saving the text file once I have the data I need in it. I've found myself now stuck, any ideas would be helpful.

Here is the code that I have so far:

```
Set b2 = ThisWorkbook

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
strPath = "C:\Users\353281\Desktop\test 134.pdf"

ie.Visible = True
ie.navigate (strPath)

Do While ie.Busy And ie.ReadyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Loop


Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 2)
    AppActivate strPath
    SendKeys "^(a)", True
    Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)

    Do
        On Error Resume Next
        SendKeys "^(c)", True
    Loop While Err.Number <> 0
np = Shell("Notepad.exe", vbNormalFocus)


AppActivate np
SendKeys "^(v)", True
'tried the SendKeys method of saving my text file here, not to much avail
SendKeys "^(s)", True

'this bit here finds the file name of strPath
a = InStrRev(strPath, "\")
b = InStrRev(strPath, ".")
c = Mid(strPath, a + 1, b - a - 1)

'haven't got anything after this point but a few failed attempts
```

(I apologize for the code being messy, I don't focus on structure until I have something together that works)

Comment: Can you create a Notepad object in the same way you're creating an IE object? (Does Notepad expose an object model??) If so, then pasting and saving should be very simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, what ended up working for me was the code as follows:

```
Dim b2 As Workbook
Dim ie As Object
Dim np As Object

Sub test4()
Set b2 = ThisWorkbook

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
strPath = "C:\Users\353281\Desktop\test 134.pdf"

ie.Visible = False
ie.navigate (strPath)

Do While ie.Busy And ie.ReadyState <> 4
    DoEvents
Loop

Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 2)
AppActivate strPath
SendKeys "^(a)", True
Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)

Do
    On Error Resume Next
    SendKeys "^(c)", True
Loop While Err.Number <> 0

ie.Quit

Set np = CreateObject("Word.Application")
AppActivate np
np.documents.Add
np.Visible = False
np.Selection.pasteandformat wdpastedefault

b = InStrRev(strPath, ".")
filenm = Mid(strPath, 1, b - 1)

np.activedocument.SaveAs2 Filename:=filenm, FileFormat:=2
np.activedocument.Close
np.Quit

np = Nothing
ie = Nothing
SendKeys "{NUMLock}", True

End Sub
```

Instead of using Notepad to create the text document, I found much more success in using Word. This code will take the pdf, open it in IE, select all the text, copy to the clipboard and then paste it onto a word document that then gets saved as a text file in the same folder as the original pdf.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
Dim NP as object

set NP = CreateObject("Notepad.Application")

'copy the text from the .PDF as you do now

NP.paste
NP.SaveAs Filename:=<your file name>
```

**Note:** this is completely untested, but should serve as a framework. I've not gone looking into the Notepad object model to confirm that my method names are correct.